# get unrepeated arrange of two dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, combinations

from **just two dicts(a, c)**, I need to find term_wMca that just gives:
**xA * xB * xc * W_ABC**. In fact I need to leave repeated ones like W_AAC, W_BBC, just ternary ones without repeat.when bigger dicts are entered by user just ternary should be calculated in term_wMca .
Is there any way to do that??

```
import sympy as sp
a = {'A': 1}
c = {'B': 1, 'C': 1}
term_wMca = 0
for k in a:
    for j in c:
        for l in c:
            term_wMca += sp.symbols(f'x{str(k)}') * sp.symbols(f'x{str(j)}') * 
                sp.symbols(f'x{str(l)}') *sp.symbols(f'W_{str(l)}{str(j)}{str(k)}')
print(term_wMca)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here using **itertools.combination module** we can **avoid repeating combination** as the following code make the solution to my problem, may be useful to someone else.

```
import sympy as sp
import itertools
a = {'A': 1}
c = {'B': 1, 'C': 1}
term_wMca = 0
term = list(sp.symbols(f'x{x}') * sp.symbols(f'x{y}') *
                sp.symbols(f'x{z}') *sp.symbols(f'W_{x}{y}{z}') for x, y in 
 itertools.combinations((c.keys()), 2) for z in (a.keys()))
for i in range(len(term)):
    term_wMca += term[i]
print('w:', type(term_wMca), term_wMca)
```

it gives:

> > 2*W_BCA*xA*xB*xC

Also, for a bigger c and a it works well:
a = {'A': 1, 'M': 1, 'N': 1}
c = {'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 1}

> > W_BCA*xA*xB*xC + W_BCM*xB*xC*xM + W_BCN*xB*xC*xN + W_BDA*xA*xB*xD + W_BDM*xB*xD*xM + W_BDN*xB*xD*xN + W_CDA*xA*xC*xD + W_CDM*xC*xD*xM + W_CDN*xC*xD*xN

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `for-loop` for each variable:

```
import sympy as sp
a = {'A': 1}
c = {'B': 1, 'C': 1}

keys = list(a.keys()) + list(c.keys())

term_wMca = 1
for k in keys:
    term_wMca *= sp.symbols(f'x{k}')

term_wMca *= sp.symbols(f'W_' + ''.join(keys))

print(term_wMca)
```

Result:

```
W_ABC * xA * xB * xC
```

Comment: this way is not useful since to include only have ternary terms then just quaternary one is made.

Comment: import sympy as sp
a = {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1 }
c = {'D': 1}

keys = list(a.keys()) + list(c.keys())

term_wMca = 1
for k in keys:
    term_wMca *= sp.symbols(f'x{k}')

term_wMca *= sp.symbols(f'W_' + ''.join(keys))

print(term_wMca)

Comment: it gives:>>> W_ABCD*xA*xB*xC*xD

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem. What would you expect as the output for this example?

Comment: It should be term_wMca  = W_ABD*xA*xB*xD + W_ACD*xA*xC*xD + W_BCD*xB*xC*xD